# DraggableFlatList not rendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am attempting to use DraggableFlatlist and nothing renders. I have tested this section of code with FlatList and it renders fine.

Test data:

```json
    const textData = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      name: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      name: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      name: 'Third Item',
    },
  ];
```

Simple text to render:

```js
  const textItem = ({ item, drag, isActive }) => (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        alignItems: "center",
    }}
    >
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
```

DraggableFlatList:

```js
    return (
        <View
          style={[
            style,
            { backgroundColor: "white", padding: 25, borderRadius: 10 },
          ]}
        >
            <DraggableFlatList
               data={textData}
               renderItem={textItem}
               keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
               style={{ flex: 1 }}
               onDragEnd={({ data }) => setData(data)}
            />
        </View>
    )
```

The versions are reasonably current:

react-native: "0.64.3"
react-native-draggable-flatlist: "^3.0.4"

I am stumped on why DraggableFlatList will render nothing while FlatList will render the text, thoughts on what I am missing?

BTW, I did look at [Draggable flatlist not rendering anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698713/draggable-flatlist-not-rendering-anything) but there was no joy.

Comment: Doesn't look wrong at the first glance. Can you post the whole code of where the DraggableFlatList is used?

Comment: renderItem={textItem} where textItem is not returning anything to renderItem function props

Comment: Vinit: Yes, I thought that too but if I change to FlatList, the textItem renders fine on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add an additional prop, *containerStyle={{ flex : 1 }}* like this:

```js
    return (
        <View
          style={[
            style,
            { backgroundColor: "white", padding: 25, borderRadius: 10 },
          ]}
        >
            <DraggableFlatList
               data={textData}
               renderItem={textItem}
               containerStyle={{ flex : 1 }}
               keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
               style={{ flex: 1 }}
               onDragEnd={({ data }) => setData(data)}
            />
        </View>
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had exactly the same problem and had no idea why it wasn't working.